# I want to get the data from the sqlalchemy table in html using jinja2 format {{all.{{item}}}} where item is the element of string and all is data

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

in my code "all" is the data taken from the sqalchemy database,now i am having another list "asked", In that list,name are of columns are stored of which details are required
but when i run this code it give me an error:
asked = ["S_NO", "FAIL_TIME", "RIGHT_TIME", "FAILURE_REMARKS"],
when i run "all.S_NO" or "all["S_NO"]" it run's perfect. but the case I defined it gives me error

```
enter code here

{% for all in data %}
   {% for item in asked: %}
       <tr>
       <td>{{all.{{item}}}}</td>
 {% endfor %}
```

flask code

```
class Data(db.Model):

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=True)
S_NO = db.Column(db.String(250) ,nullable=False, unique= True)
STN_CODE = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
STN_NAME = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
ADSTE = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
SSE= db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
ROUTE=db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False)
SEC=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
DIV=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
FAIL_TIME=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
RIGHT_TIME=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
DURATION=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
FAILURE_REMARKS=db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
NAME_OF_GEAR_FAILED=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
TYPE_OF_MAIN_GEAR_FAILED =db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
Failed_Gear_Desc=db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False)
DEPTT=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
Cause=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
Train_Detention=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):

    return f"< S_NO ={self.S_NO}, STN_CODE={self.STN_CODE},STN_NAME = {self.STN_NAME}, ADSTE ={self.ADSTE},SSE= {self.SSE}, ROUTE={self.ROUTE},SEC= {self.SEC}, DIV= {self.DIV},FAIL_TIME= {self.FAIL_TIME},RIGHT_TIME= {self.RIGHT_TIME},DURATION= {self.DURATION},FAILURE_REMARKS= {self.FAILURE_REMARKS}, NAME_OF_GEAR_FAILED= {self.NAME_OF_GEAR_FAILED}, TYPE_OF_MAIN_GEAR_FAILED = {self.TYPE_OF_MAIN_GEAR_FAILED}, Failed_Gear_Desc={ self.Failed_Gear_Desc}, DEPTT={ self.DEPTT}, Cause={ self.Cause},Train_Detention= {self.Train_Detention}>"


@app.route("/")
def home():
new_data = db.session.query(Data).all()
demand = ["S_NO", "FAIL_TIME", "RIGHT_TIME", "FAILURE_REMARKS"]

return render_template("index.html", data = new_data,header = failure_event, asked =demand)
```

new data look

```
< S_NO =2, STN_CODE=JHI,STN_NAME = Jind, ADSTE =ROK,SSE= SSE/SIG/JHI, ROUTE=D,SEC= DLI(EX) - BTI(EX), DIV= DLI,FAIL_TIME= 5/19/21 3:20,RIGHT_TIME= 5/19/21 5:55,DURATION= 2:35:00,FAILURE_REMARKS= YELLOW ASPECT LED UNIT WAS DEFECTIVE , SAME REPLACED AT 04:15. LONG DURATION DUE TO NO TEST MARGIN AVAILABLE. LDM-04/05/21, LDI-08/05/21. OLD LED MAKE - SARNARTI INC. , NAME_OF_GEAR_FAILED= UP STR. SIGNAL S-43 FAILED FOR LINE NO. 7, TYPE_OF_MAIN_GEAR_FAILED = SIGNAL, Failed_Gear_Desc=MACLS, DEPTT=SNT, Cause=LED DEF,Train_Detention= LOAD=15">
```

type of data is

```
<class 'list'>
```

error is defined below

{{all.{{item}}}}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number

I tried my best to make my problem understandable, if I failed please let me know so that I can try again, It's my first time on StackOverflow

Comment: What does `data` contain? Show the flask code as well.

Comment: Thanks for checking my issue i have updated my code with flask code, if you can please help me and if you need something more i will upload that also.   Thanks

Comment: Most of the times, its better to do complex task in flask code itself rethat than doing it in template.

Comment: Can you modify question by showing what your `new_data` looks like and its data type?

Comment: uploaded the new_data look as well as the data type, please take a look and help me ........Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the def **repr**(self):

get the result in the form of dict

```
class Data(db.Model):

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=True)
S_NO = db.Column(db.String(250) ,nullable=False, unique= True)
STN_CODE = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
STN_NAME = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
ADSTE = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
SSE= db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
ROUTE=db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False)
SEC=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
DIV=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
FAIL_TIME=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
RIGHT_TIME=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
DURATION=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
FAILURE_REMARKS=db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
NAME_OF_GEAR_FAILED=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
TYPE_OF_MAIN_GEAR_FAILED =db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
Failed_Gear_Desc=db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False)
DEPTT=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
Cause=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
Train_Detention=db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

def dobule_to_dict(self):
    result = {}
    for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
        if getattr(self, key) is not None:
            result[key] = str(getattr(self, key))
        else:
            result[key] = getattr(self, key)
    return result
```

outside the class use the below function

```
def to_json(all_vendors):
v = [ ven.dobule_to_dict() for ven in all_vendors ]
return v
users = Data.query.all()
sheet_data = to_json(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to do complex logic part in flask itself rather than in template.

Use this to get the values of database and to pass it to template:

```py
@app.route("/")
def home():
new_data = db.session.query(Data).all()
demand = ["S_NO", "FAIL_TIME", "RIGHT_TIME", "FAILURE_REMARKS"]

all_data_item = []
for data in new_data:
  for item in demand:
    if item in data:
      all_data_item.append(data.item)

return render_template("index.html", data = all_data_item,header = failure_event, asked =demand)
```

In template:

```py
{% for d in data %}
      <td>{{d}}</td>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it give back an error   " Data' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: Is your new_data dictionary or list? Can you check my updated answer?

Comment: new_data is a list

Comment: If it is a list then why is it like this `S_NO =2, STN_CODE=JHI,STN_NAME = Jind`? List does not store key value. Your hint is unclear. Update question by stating what your `new_data` taken from Database looks like

Comment: @Himanshurana is your problem solved? Please tick my answer if it helped

Comment: i have posted another problem , can you help me in that also, if you can it will be very greatful to me.